# My Marigold plant that I started from seed is starting to droop, what do I do?

Tags: flowers, plant-care

[image]
Please help ASAP I do not want my little plant to die, just last week it was doing spectacular and now nothing.

Comment: Can you add some more information please - where are you in the world? Is the plant indoors or outside? Have you recently moved it outside, and/or repotted it? Does the pot its in have drainage holes?

Comment: It has drainage holes, I have not repotted it, it has been outdoors since the day I planted the seeds, I live in Northridge California its always hot out here.